# Bash file: wrong SHA512 hash in while loop

Tags: bash

I've created a bash script to hash my user's passwords. These credentials are stored in a file called "usernamemdp.txt" with the following format :

> Username1 password1
>
> Username2 password2

My bash script create two output files, with the content :

> username1 password1
>
> username2 password2

for the first file, called "username.txt" (the content is the same, with the lowercase username), and :

> username1 password1 sha512ofpassword1
>
> username2 password2 sha512ofpassword2

for the second file, called "usernamesha.txt"

Here is the script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set input/output files variables
INFILE="usernamemdp.txt"
OUTFILE="username.txt"
OUTSHAFILE="usernamesha.txt"
#create and/or empty output files
> $OUTFILE
> $OUTSHAFILE
#loop through the input file
while read LINE; do
    #take the first word as username, and lowercase it
    USERNAME=$(echo $LINE | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | awk '{print $1}')
    #take the second word as password
    REALPASS=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')
    #hash the password
    SHAPASSWORD=$(echo $REALPASS | openssl dgst -sha512)
    #output to the first file
    echo "$USERNAME $REALPASS" >> $OUTFILE
    #output to the second file
    echo "$USERNAME $REALPASS $SHAPASSWORD" >> $OUTSHAFILE
done < $INFILE
```

The issue is that the hashed password is never the one that I expect. When I echo the variables, `$REALPASS` is ok with no trailing spaces, but `$SHAPASSWORD` is not good.
I've tried to replace `openssl dgst -sha512` with `mkpasswd -m sha512`, but the results are the same.

When I type the hashing command on my console (`echo -n bite | openssl dgst -sha512`), the output is correct:

> (stdin)=
>   3c71cad6982778650fcecd4f37a34ef4349f6e01adaf3cddcb804856c92096b698411c42c7d68f9d6e380c0b487b4019203956496eaa7cac9ac96fdcf3d63dfd

When I run the script, the hashed password is not what I expect:

> (stdin)=
>   0e73a7f0a2c108e3f29cf3220a464e8cd7f515b99a65d77f1c82696342f77ba20345102a803686a81370b1a48302fc191055e215fa3ca1b0841571c924ff01ee

I'm suspecting a bad usage of `echo` and `$()`, but I'm stuck and don't understand my mistake.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that this naive sha512 approach is a highly insecure way of hashing passwords. sha512crypt is safe, but very different from this.

Comment: @thatotherguy Can you elaborate on why is this a "highly insecure way of hashing psswords" please?

Comment: [This article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) explains some of what happens when you don't salt and stretch your hashes. Tl;dr: use a respected library that knows how to protect against gpu crackers and precomputation attacks. Don't fall for [Schneier's law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)

Comment: I agree with what you said about password security, but I didnt ask for passwords security tips because when I have only 2 pennies I dont really need/want an expensive, complex time consuming, all-kind-of-attack-proof safe deposit box for it... Anyway, thank you for the great resource on salted password hashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In script:

```
SHAPASSWORD=$(echo $REALPASS | openssl dgst -sha512)
```

In text:

```
echo -n bite | openssl dgst -sha512
```

Notice the missing `-n` in the script. A newline at the end will make a difference to the digest.

Also, the incorrect SHA512 digest that you mentioned is the digest for

```
bite\r\n
```

Not only does it have a newline at the end, but a carriage return as well. This may come from having created the input file on a Windows machine.

I have not looked too closely at the rest of the script, except to notice that it won't cope with passwords that contain spaces due to the way the parsing is done by `awk` (splits on whitespaces).

I'd suggest you quote your variables, and use `printf` which has a more consistent behaviour across shells in comparison to `echo`:

```
printf '%s' "$REALPASS" | ...
```

I'm additionally more than a little concerned that you're storing user's passwords in clear text in a text file. There is already a system in place for handling (login) passwords.

Comment: Passwords are stored temporarily, for a SQL insert.
When I use `echo -n $REALPASS | openssl...` in the script, the hash is incorrect. I've tested with `printf '%s' "$REALPASS" | ...` and the result is incorrect and different from the echo'ed version, even if `printf '%s' "bite"` gave me the correct output on the console.

Comment: @Ayak973 The passwords you read have a `\r` at the end. You have created the input file on a Windows machine?

Comment: Damn, someone send me the file by email. That person has a windows machine... I've removed the \r and everything is ok now !

Comment: +1 for `printf '%s'` instead of `echo` -- `echo -n` is a compatibility nightmare! BTW, I'd also recommend using lowercase variable names (to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps ones that have special meanings), and also using `while IFS=$' \t\n\r` read username realpass; do` -- that'll handle the line splitting without `awk` *and* trim carriage returns if you forget to convert the file.